# Regular expressions for different attributes

Tags: regex

I am having trouble extracting segmentations. For example, what kind of regular expressions can we write to extract the **state**? What about the **ratings** and **parking**? I want to be able to write regular expressions which will give me ratings of that restaurant that is 5.0 (without star rating written after it). I don't know how to get values before or after a particular word without including it in the answer.

Comment: What programming language/tool are you using? The regex features available depend on what you're using.

Comment: I just want regex which I can test in sites like this:
http://rubular.com/

(I need to understand this for project)

Answer (score 1):

You didn't say it outright, but it sounds like you are [screen scraping](http://www.google.com/url?url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_scraping#Screen_scraping&rct=j&q=screen%20scraping&usg=AFQjCNHOxyvi6x-W285RsBBS1-oVERClXQ&sa=X&ei=a8ctT8eDAufaiQLjw4jVCg&ved=0CHkQygQwAA&cad=rja). If that's the case you might want to consider using an existing package to get to the data and *then* use regexps to get the detail. If you are using Python I recommend [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) because it deals with all of the crap in modern (and not so modern) web pages.

Answer (score 0):

```
(\d.\d) star rating\n.*?\n.*?\n.*?\n[^,]*, ([A-Z]{2}).*Parking: (Yes|No)
```

And then use capture groups 1, 2 and 3.

Comment: For what it's worth, this only works if the lines are the same (or at least in the correct order). I would recommend using multiple/simple regular expressions on each line instead of constructing one gigantic regex.

Comment: Can you please tell me how I can get words after particular words? For Example: If I want the value of Neighborhood, how can I write a regex so that it only shows Korean and not the entire line? I need to test this in site like: rubular.com

Answer (score 0):

First, I don't see how your original regex would work. Expressions between parenthesis usually denote capturing groups, so it would'd match those in the text. Unless, of course, you escape them:

```
(\(\d{3}\)\s\d{3}-\d{4})
```

Second, in case you're not aware of how capturing groups work, you'll have to look up your tool/language documentation to see how to use them. Try them with Joey's answer, and you should be fine.

In JavaScript, for instance, you access them like array indices:

```
var exec = /yourregex/.exec("yourstring");
var group1 = exec[1];
var group2 = exec[2];
etc
```

[Here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) is some info on capturing groups, in general. I'm assuming by your comment that you're using Ruby, so [this tutorial](http://strugglingwithruby.blogspot.com/2009/05/regular-expressions-in-ruby.html) may also be helpful. I'm not experienced with Ruby, so I can't provide more info, but the links I posted should help you get started.

**Update**: after some more Googling, I finally found the syntax:

```
all,g1 = *(/Neighborhood\:\ (\w+)/.match("Neighborhood: Koreatown"))
# all = "Neighborhood: Koreatown"
# g1 = "Koreatown"
```

Use more variables if there are more groups in the same regex.

Comment: The "Match result" shows the whole match, but the "Match groups" show `1. Koreatown`. That means if you extract the first capture group of your match, if will contain the string "Koreatown".

Comment: Oh I see Match groups after putting in your query. But then what?

Comment: Well, as I said, I don't know Ruby, so I'm afraid I can't help you. And for some reason I couldn't find a quick answer Googling it, so I'm lost...

Comment: But the problem is I need a general regex for multiple sources of this kind. That means I cant manually change Koreatown everytime... =(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7352/discussion-between-mgibsonbr-and-user807496)